# First row should be fixed in Datagrid view during Sorting in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have a collection of objects that is bound to DataGrid view,
First row will be the main row. Whenever user sorts the datagrid using any colulm header, Main row(i.e row 0 should always remain on top at 0th position only), all other rows should get sorted.
How to add the sortdescription for this in Sorting event handler?

e.g. 
I've list of 10 objects in 10 rows,
Row 0 is the main or the master row(which will contain the master object).
When the user sorts the datagrid, then master object has to remain at Row 0 only
but other 9 object can be sorted accordingly..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `Sorting` event for the `DataGrid` to implement your custom sorting:

```
private ListSortDirection _direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
private void dg_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
    _direction = _direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? ListSortDirection.Descending : ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    view.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("YourBoolProperty", ListSortDirection.Descending));
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(e.Column.SortMemberPath, _direction));
    e.Column.SortDirection = _direction;
}
```

Comment: Thanks..Thought the question was not clearly asked previously.
Have changed it now.. How to add the SortDescription for first row? @mm8

Comment: I have already answered your question...You need to set a property of the "main row". This property is called "YourBoolProperty" in my example.